# WeatherStation : Mysql query join & average on tables

Tags: mysql, join, weather

I have two tables like that :

temperature :

```
+---------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id      | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| date    | datetime            | YES  | UNI | NULL    |                |
| capteur | int(11)             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| valeur  | float(3,1)          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

humidite :

```
+---------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id      | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| date    | datetime            | YES  | UNI | NULL    |                |
| capteur | int(11)             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| valeur  | int(11)             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I have values recorded on those two tables, not at the same time (Around 1 record each minute).

If I enter this command, I get average values for each hour for the last 24h (so, 24 rows) :

```
$sql->query('SELECT hour(date) AS humhour,ROUND(AVG(valeur),1) AS avghum FROM humidite WHERE date >= (now() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) GROUP BY HOUR(date) ORDER BY DATE;');
```

Now, I try to get the same thing, but with both tables. Ie, for all value between 0h00 and 0h59, I want average of all temperature and average of all humidity values.

I try this command :

```
$result = $sql->query('
    SELECT  hour(temperature.date) AS hourtemp,
            hour(humidite.date) AS hourhum,
            ROUND(AVG(temperature.valeur),1) AS avgtemp,
            ROUND(AVG(humidite.valeur),1) AS avghum
    FROM temperature
    INNER JOIN humidite on hour(temperature.date) = hour(humidite.date)  
    WHERE temperature.date >= (now() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)
    GROUP BY HOUR(date)
    ORDER BY DATE;');
```

An idea ?

Thank you !

Comment: GROUP BY HOUR(temperature.date) ? But I'm not sure it will work. date is a column for humidite and temperature, so MySQL cannot know which column it has to use.

Comment: I added more informations and the code is quite working, thanks to another page of stackoverflow. Please, continue to read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19029112/mysql-join-two-tables-based-on-async-time-and-average-values)